# .Net Core template has a compile warning CS0108 for property SettingManager

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to remove all build warnings in the .net core template. I have reduced it to one:

- Code: CS0108
- Description: 'Views_Shared__Layout.SettingManager' hides inherited member 'AbpRazorPage.SettingManager'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
- Project: AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc
- File: module-zero-core-template\aspnet-core\src\AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Views\Shared_Layout.g.cshtml.cs
- Line: 1869

I am trying to find a way to eliminate or suppress this warning in the smallest possible scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the setting manager in the layout.cshtml directly.

> Remove unnecessary setting manager injection since it has been injected in AbpRazorPage

See the changes in
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/450

Comment: Thanks. In future, I should probably look at github for upcoming changes to the code in question.